# ASP Multiview controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender, multiview

i have some issues right here with ASP Multiview which i can't seem to figure out.

I have this page called Submit.aspx, it is fired up via iframe in AJAX toolkit popup modal extender. I have applied Multiview to this form. When it loads, it will display ActiveIndex 0. If user has clicked the submit button,  it will change ActiveIndex to 1 which display "your form has been submitted, etc. and it will auto close via javascript. When i click on Submit link again, the ActiveViewIndex is still stucked at 1, how do i go about programming it to sort of reset/clear the ActiveViewIndex?

Comment: What exactly auto closes via JS, the message or the form?

Answer (score 0):

You could specifically set the MultiView value with MultiView.SetActiveView(view value)

Comment: I can, but where do I add that in?

Comment: You could check this out-http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shubham0987/how-to-use-multiview-in-Asp-Net/